# Firefox doesn't remember self-signed certificate

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

My university wireless internet has a login page that uses a self signed certificate. Firefox asks if I'm sure that I want to use that website and if I am, to mark as an exception.

The thing is, I check the box "Permanently store this exception" and that doesn't work. On every new boot, Firefox ask the same thing. Is there a way to truly mark the cert as an exception?

[image: firefox security exception]

Comment: Have you verified you are always sent the same certificate, in some cases, a server might send a client a dynamic certificate

Comment: Try going to `Edit -> Preferences`, then `Advanced -> Certificates -> View Certificates`, then check the `Servers` tab and see what certificates are saved there. Adding screenshots to your question might help...

Comment: The `1.1.1.1` address and the certificate are there.